# Using a proxy with Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, proxy

for the past two days I've been trying to use a proxy with Selenium, that's not *exactly* the issue though. The issue is that the proxy is **private** meaning it needs authentication to use it (Username and Password) but I can't figure out how to do it.

I'm using a Firefox driver, with a profile like so:

```
    FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
    firefoxProfile.SetPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
    firefoxProfile.SetPreference("network.proxy.http", "23.95.115.87");
    firefoxProfile.SetPreference("network.proxy.http_port", 80);
    var driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://ipchicken.com");
```

I figured that it would ask me for the username and password (in a dialog box) yet nothing happens, it just navigates to the webpage, and displays my own IP. I can't find anything really on this, any help guys? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in Selenium but I can help you in making your proxy authentication free.

If you are on Windows, download something like CC-Proxy ( Its free for a single user) and add your proxy as a cascading proxy. This will create a local proxy server on your computer which won't require username/password. Then you can use the local proxy server in selenium.

If you are on Linux, you can use wine to run CC-Proxy or you can use tinyproxy or squid ( it is an overkill).

Comment if you face problem in setting up CC-Proxy or tinyproxy.

Comment: If I didn't need it with authentication, then I would have just used Selenium itself for it. Thank you for answer though.

Comment: @Frank I thought you are behind some corporate proxy and are not allowed to access internet directly. One other thing that you can try it put proxy like this username:password@proxyaddress

In your case it would be username:password@23.95.115.87

Comment: I can get back to you on that, I'm 99% sure it throws a 'Not In Correct Format" exception.