# How to correctly set up a proxy with Selenium C# PhantomJSDriver?

Tags: c#, selenium, proxy, phantomjs

How do I **correctly** set up a proxy with Selenium C# PhantomJSDriver in a C# console application?

I have looked high/low at all online docs and similar post with no success:

- [Add proxy to PhantomJSDriver (Selenium C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18921099/add-proxy-to-phantomjsdriver-selenium-c)
- [Using a proxy with Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27495567/using-a-proxy-with-selenium)
- [How to Setup Private Proxy with Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30674994/how-to-setup-private-proxy-with-selenium)

Here's my code:

```
var options = new PhantomJSOptions();
options.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.Proxy,"123.456.748.99:80");
IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(options);
```

Running this code I get the following error(s):

> **ERROR: Unexpected error. TypeError - undefined is not an object (evaluating 'proxyCapability["proxyType"].toLowerCase')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
PhantomJSDriverService service = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.AddArgument(string.Format("--proxy-auth={0}:{1}", proxyUsername, proxyPassword));
service.AddArgument(string.Format("--proxy={0}:{1}", proxyAddress, proxyPort));

IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(service);
```

in service you have more options to add if you need.

Comment: Thank you - this works! Okay I see what we are doing now is adding Command-line Options to PhantomJS.exe as shown on the [Command Line Interface](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html) page of the PhantomJS API.

Comment: @Newport99 Glad to help.